# If $A$ is $3\times 3$ matrix with eigenvalues $1, -1, 0$ then what is determinant of $I+A^{100}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

My textbook's answer is $100$. How to find determinant of this matrix? can anyone explain? please.

Comment: Is it the determinant of $(I+A)^{100}$, or $I+A^{100}$?

Comment: it is I+A^{100}, Identity matrix plus matrix A raise to power 100

Comment: Then I have no idea how your textbook comes to that answer. As an example, one can choose $A=\text{diag}(1,0,-1)$ in which case $I+A^{100}=\text{diag}(2,1,2)$ with determinant 4. (The situation with $(I+A)^{100}$ isn't much better, though, since $\det(I+A)=0$.)

Comment: if A^{100} = diag(1,0,-1) and when we add I (identity matrix) to A then A remains same then how determinant become 4

Comment: @T.Noor First off, $A^{100}=\text{diag}(1^{100},0^{100},(-1)^{100})=\text{diag}(1,0,1)$. Then, when we add $I$ to it, we get $I+A^{100}=\text{diag}(1,1,1)+\text{diag}(1,0,1)=\text{diag}(2,1,2)$. Adding the identity matrix to a matrix does not keep it the same. Matrices stay the same when they are added by the zero matrix or multiplied by the identity matrix.

Comment: yes sir, I got it now @Noble Mushtak thanks a lot

Comment: thanks sir @semiclassical thank you very much for help

Answer (score 5):

Let $v$ be an eigenvector.  Then $A^2v=AAv=A\lambda v=\lambda Av=\lambda^2v$, and in general $A^nv=\lambda^nv$.  So $(I+A^{100})v=(1+\lambda^{100})v$, and the eigenvalues are $2,2,1$, so the determinant is 4.

Comment: i got it.. thanks